# IPv6 Routing // Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address

Tags: routing, ipv6

I want to setup Dual Stack on Customer VMs. The Router is a VM too. Running on Debian Wheezy. Overall virtualized by ESXi. IPv4 is working fine.

Ping from Customer VM

```
ping6 -c 1 heise.de
PING heise.de(redirector.heise.de) 56 data bytes
From fe80::20c:29ff:fea2:cb92 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address

--- heise.de ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

|customer vm| --eth0--> <---eth1-- |routing vm| --eth0--> (WAN)

**Router VM**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address XXXX:4f8:200:640e::
    netmask 128
    gateway fe80::1
# secondary network interface eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address XXX.76.233.142
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    broadcast XXX.76.233.143
iface eth1 inet6 static
    address    XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1
    netmask    64
```

netstat -rn -A inet6

`Kernel-IPv6-Routentabelle
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::/128        ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::/64         ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
::/0                           fe80::1                    UG   1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   243 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1  5018 lo
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::/128        ::                         Un   0   1     9 lo
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::/128        ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1/128       ::                         Un   0   1   134 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::20c:29ff:fea2:cb92/128   ::                         Un   0   1    19 lo
fe80::250:56ff:fe00:4d1a/128   ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   243 lo`

ping6 -c 1 heise.de

```
PING heise.de(redirector.heise.de) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from redirector.heise.de: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=5.46 ms

--- heise.de ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.467/5.467/5.467/0.000 ms
```

Ping the customer vm

ping6 -c 1 XXXX:4f8:200:640e::3

```
PING XXXX:4f8:200:640e::3(XXXX:4f8:200:640e::3) 56 data bytes

--- XXXX:4f8:200:640e::3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

**Customer VM**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address XXX.76.233.137
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    network XXX.76.233.128
    broadcast XXX.76.233.143
    gateway XXX.76.233.142
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 213.133.98.98
    dns-search XXXX.XX
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address XXXX:4f8:200:640e::3
    netmask 64
    gateway XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1
```

netstat -rn -A inet6

`Kernel-IPv6-Routentabelle
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
XXXX:4f8:200:640e::/64         ::                         U    256 0     1 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
::/0                           2a01:4f8:200:640e::1       UG   1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     4 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1    13 lo
fe80::20c:29ff:fed8:326e/128   ::                         Un   0   1     6 lo
fe80::cc1c:86ff:fe4a:47d3/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     4 lo`

Ping the Router VM

ping6 -c 1 XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1 (XXXX:4f8:200:640e:: is also successful)

```
PING XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1(XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.217 ms

--- XXXX:4f8:200:640e::1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.217/0.217/0.217/0.000 ms
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

There are 2 vSwitches

vSwitch0

Attached to the physical nic. The Router VM is connected to this vSwitch via eth0.

vSwitch1

There are all Customer VMs and the Router VM(eth1) attached.

See: http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/VMware_ESXi/en#Preparations_in_the_vSphere_client

Comment: What is your vSwitch configuration? How are the VMs connected?

Comment: I've added the vSwitch configuration.